# Where can I find a clear diagram of the SPECK algorithm?

Tags: lightweight, speck

Where can I find a clear algorithm diagram of SPECK algorithm? I want to follow steps to write ARM assembly code.

Comment: The original paper has some good code in the supporting documentation.  There's also ASM code in the linux kernel for SPECK that was removed as things got AES-NI.

Answer (score 3):

> Where can I find a clear algorithm diagram of speck algorithm?

Have you looked at [the spec wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_(cipher)) - that (at the time I write this) includes both an algorithm diagram and a C implementation (however, the C implementation uses more #define's than I would use to explain things...)

Comment: Personally I would use precisely zero defines to explain things :)